# (Possibly Lebesgue) integral over an indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have trouble understanding the following integral:

\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{1} \textbf{1}_{[x\geq b]}db
\end{equation*}

I don't know any way to integrate it "normally" like doing a Riemann integral. But I don't know how to analyze it as a Lebesgue integral, either. For example, $b$ is supposed to be a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra (presumably Borel sets) over $[0,1]$, yet the function $\textbf{1}_{[x\geq b]}$ implies that $b$ is a variable.

I appreciate any insights explaining the integral and solving my confusion.

Comment: Bad notation. The upper limit of integration should not be the variable of integration.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry I made a typo. just corrected it

Comment: Think about the example $\int_0^11\{x<\frac 1 2\}dx$ and it should be clearer

Answer (score 1):

Here $b$ is the variable of integration and $x$ is fixed. Let $f(b)=1$ if $b \leq x$ and $0$ otherwise. Then the given intergal is $\int_0^{1}f(b)db$ which is equal to the measure of $\{b\in [0,1]: b \leq x\}$. So the value is  $x$ if $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $1$ if $x >1$ and $0$ if $x<0$.